# How can I read texel data on a separate thread in D3D11?

Tags: directx11, multithreading

In D3D10, I load a staging texture onto my GPU memory, then map it in order to access its texel data on the CPU. This is done on a separate thread, not the thread I render with. I just call the device methods, and it works.

In D3D11 I load the staging texture onto my GPU, but to access it (i.e. Map it) I need to use the Context, not the device. Can't use the immediate context, since the immediate context can only be used by a single thread at a time. But I also can't use a deferred context to Read from the texture to the CPU:

"If you call Map on a deferred context, you can only pass D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_NO_OVERWRITE, or both to the MapType parameter. Other D3D11_MAP-typed values are not supported for a deferred context."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff476457.aspx

Ok, so what am I supposed to do now? It is common to use textures to store certain data (heightmaps for instance) and you obviously have to be able to access that data for it to be useful. Is there no way for me to do this in a separate thread with D3D11?

Comment: Deferred contexts are just recording data to command lists (as far as I know), then the immediate context executes the recorded commands. You could use a mutex to lock the immediate context and map to that, I think. By the way, you should not map textures, but set their shaderresourceviews to a shader slot.

Comment: Hi! I want my CPU to access the texture data in a separate thread (something that btw worked just fine in D3D10). How would setting the texture's view to a shader slot help me with that?

Comment: Code that "works" but has threading bugs can often not obviously manifest for a while. D3D has never been very multi-threaded friendly (and still isn't, even the "multithreaded rendering" that D3D11 purports to have is just command list recording, as noted above).

Answer (score 3):

Once a texture is mapped to the CPU, its texel data is in CPU-accessible memory, which can be read by all threads, including your worker thread.

Thus, you should map the resource in your main thread using your immediate context, and then perform all your reads and assorted dependent work (which is generally where the real need for a worker thread would be) on a worker thread, setting some state or signal to notify the main thread when the worker is complete and the main thread can unmap the resource.

If map stall time (on the main thread) is an issue as well, consider the `D3D11_MAP_FLAG_DO_NOT_WAIT` flag (make sure to check if `DXGI_ERROR_WAS_STILL_DRAWING` is returned and then do something else if so).

To make the best use of this scenario, you're likely going to want to move as many post-read operations to the worker thread as you can (to load it), and also make sure you have other things the main thread can do if the resource is not mappable at the time (perhaps move on to another resource, for example) to make sure it stays loaded, otherwise there wasn't much point in multithreading the work.

Comment: Uh, ok, but the texture mapping is part of the loading function. One state is drawing while another state loads. Clean separation of tasks in a multithreaded environment. Now I need to somehow add the mapping code from one state to a completely unrelated part of my code because... duh D3D11 broke the multithreading ability D3D10 already had?

Comment: As far as I am aware, D3D10 had no way to guarantee that behavior you are describing. It may have *appeared to work* but it was likely a ticking time bomb. D3D's "multithreaded" capability is basically supporting the recording of commands; not the execution. It does not (and has not) support "multithreaded rendering" or "multithreaded device access."

Comment: If you want clean separation of tasks, divorce them from D3D, which is synchronization point due to its API design and driver device access; for example, load your texture data off the disk *without* D3D and perform whatever post-map operations you want to do in a worker thread. When that is done, signal the main thread which creates a new texture with the until-now purely CPU-side data (or, in fact, just use the deferred context's Map and discard the whole existing buffer, splatting the new CPU-side memory into it).

Comment: "As far as I am aware, D3D10 had no way to guarantee that behavior you are describing."  Sorry, but you are wrong. D3D10 internally locks the device whenever one of its method is called. Thus, my original D3D10 code, was 100% full proof. Now, if I want the equivalent behaviour in D3D11 I need to manually add locks whenever I use D3D11's context. Yeah, this is going to be fun...... It's messy, and its something D3D11 could have kept from D3D10 as an option to be as a flag in the device constructor.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for taking the time to post. It's just frustrating finding yourself having to resort to 'messier' code when upgrading APIs. It should be the other way around!

Comment: Oh, I see what you are referring to now; yes, you could pass a flag to the device that would cause it to take internal locks to protect it's own state as far back as D3D9 (maybe earlier). But that doesn't cause it to support concurrent operations on the physical device like you are asking for: copying back resources from the GPU on CPU worker threads while the GPU is still potentially rendering (from a command buffer issued on the main thread). That's why Map can only do discardable/no-overwrite maps on the deferred context (and why the DO_NOT_WAIT flag exists).

Comment: I think, if you're careful, you can do it with two semaphores and don't need to pepper locks all over.

Comment: Hi. My understanding is different. In d3d10, if I map a buffer, it is locked. In fact, unless I specify the singleThreaded flag in the d3d10.device constructor, then the device itself will be locked as well. It, and the buffer, will be unlocked when I Unmap the buffer. So there is no concurrent operation happening on any resource. I can call the methods from separate threads and everything will work out of the box. No, I'm not really editing and rendering the data at the same time. But I am using 2 threads to do two different tasks without having to deal with synchronizing them.

Comment: and there are comments being deleted left and right. I don't think that is particularly helpful. Even if I or anyone else post info that isn't 100 correct, just pointing it out in the discussion is enough to clear up any potential misunderstandings by other readers. I think in the end they probably would get a better grasp of the subject from the entire discussion.

Comment: Comments aren't for extended discussion, that should be taken to [chat], but you lack the reputation for me to import the conversation there, so I am trying to do things to circumvent that (and it's not working); this discussion we are having is largely due in part to my misunderstanding you initially and really has no impact on my answer.

Comment: Ah ok, no problem.